# Is a cloud service suitable for this application?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud

I'm looking for details of the cloud services popping up (eg. Amazon/Azure) and am wondering if they would be suitable for my app.

My application basically has a single table database which is about 500GB. It grows by 3-5 GB/Day. 
I need to extract text data from it, about 1 million rows at a time, filtering on about 5 columns. This extracted data is usually about 1-5 GB and zips up to 100-500MB and then made available on the web.

There are some details of my existing implementation here
[One 400GB table, One query - Need Tuning Ideas (SQL2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350318)

So, my question:
Would the existing cloud services be suitable to host this type of app? What would the cost be to store this amount of data and bandwidth (bandwidth usage would be about 2GB/day)?

Are the persistence systems suitable for storing large flat tables like this, and do they offer the ability to search on a number of columns?

My current implementation runs on sub $10k hardware so it wouldn't make sense to move if costs are much higher than, say, $5k/yr.

Comment: Does the data need to be accessible from elsewhere? If not, why would you incur the cost of "bandwidth usage would be about 2GB/day"?

Comment: Yes, the few GB (zipped to a few hundred meg) needs to be accessible. Plus the 3-5 GB (also compressed 10 fold) added to the DB needs to be uploaded.

Comment: assuming that this is NOSQL, based on the fact that it is a single table. this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Given the large volume of data and the rate that it's growing, I don't think that Amazon would be a good option. I'm assuming that you'll want to be storing the data on a persistent storage. But with EC2 you need to allocate a given amount of storage and attach it as a disk. Unless you want to allocate a really large amount of space (and then will be paying for unused disc space), you will have to constantly be adding more discs. I did a quick back of the envalop calculation and I estimate it will cost between $2,500 - $10,000 per year for hosting. It's difficult for me to estimate accurately because of all of the variable things that amazon charges for (instance uptime, storage space, bandwidth, disc io, etc.) Here's the [EC2 pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) .

Comment: Why not using a Document Database? Why a relational database to query 1 single table? NoSQL db is way faster on this kind approaches, and for example, MongoHQ offers SSD drives witch will be lovely for this kinda application... why EC2? Why Relational Db?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is non-relational data (can't do relational data on a single table) you could consider using Azure Table Storage which is a storage mechanism designed for non-relational structured data.

The problem that you will have here is that Azure Tables only have a primary index and therefore cannot be indexed by 5 columns as you require. Unless you store the data 5 times, indexed each time by the column you wish to filter on. Not sure that would work out very cost-effective though.

Costs for Azure Table storage is from as little as 8c USD per Gig per month, depending on how much data you store. There are also charges per transaction and charges for Egress data.
For more info on pricing check here; http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/advanced/

Where do you need to access this data from?
How is it written to?

Based on this there could be other options to consider too, like Azure Drives etc.